# How to generate a big data stream on the fly

Tags: scala, playframework-2.1

I have to generate a big file on the fly. Reading to the database and send it to the client.
I read some documentation and i did this

```
val streamContent: Enumerator[Array[Byte]] = Enumerator.outputStream {
        os => 
              // new PrintWriter() read from database and for each record 
              // do some logic and write
              // to outputstream
      }
      Ok.stream(streamContent.andThen(Enumerator.eof)).withHeaders(
              CONTENT_DISPOSITION -> s"attachment; filename=someName.csv"
        )
```

Im rather new to scala in general only a week so don't guide for my reputation.

My questions are :

1) Is this the best way? I found this if i have a big file, this will load in memory, and also don't know what is the chunk size in this case, if it will send for each `write()` is not to convenient.

2)  I found this method `Enumerator.fromStream(data : InputStream, chunkedSize : int)`  a little better cause it has a chunk-size, but i don't have an inputStream cause im creating the file on the fly.

Comment: Chunk size is by default set to `1024 * 8` . I think that the size depends on your choice whether you want to send bigger or smaller chunks.

Comment: @goral how do you know that `Enumerator.outputStream` chunk by `1024*8` ??

Comment: I don't know about outputStream, you were talking about `fromStream` method and in specs that is set as default value

Comment: @goral sorry if my question was unclear, i already know about fromStream, i was asking about .outputStream

Answer (score 4):

There's a note in the [docs for `Enumerator.outputStream`](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.iteratee.Enumerator%24):

> Not *[sic!]* that calls to write will not block, so if the iteratee that is being fed to is slow to consume the input, the OutputStream will not push back. This means it should not be used with large streams since there is a risk of running out of memory.

If this can happen depends on your situation. If you can and will generate Gigabytes in seconds, you should probably try something different. I'm not exactly sure what, but I'd start at `Enumerator.generateM()`. For many cases though, your method is perfectly fine. Have a look [at this example by Gaëtan Renaudeau for serving a Zip file that's generated on the fly in the same way you're using it](http://greweb.me/2012/11/play-framework-enumerator-outputstream/):

```
val enumerator = Enumerator.outputStream { os =>
  val zip = new ZipOutputStream(os);
  Range(0, 100).map { i =>
    zip.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry("test-zip/README-"+i+".txt"))
    zip.write("Here are 100000 random numbers:\n".map(_.toByte).toArray)
    // Let's do 100 writes of 1'000 numbers
    Range(0, 100).map { j =>
      zip.write((Range(0, 1000).map(_=>r.nextLong).map(_.toString).mkString("\n")).map(_.toByte).toArray);
    }
    zip.closeEntry()
  }
  zip.close()
}
Ok.stream(enumerator >>> Enumerator.eof).withHeaders(
  "Content-Type"->"application/zip", 
  "Content-Disposition"->"attachment; filename=test.zip"
)
```

Please keep in mind that `Ok.stream` has been replaced by `Ok.chunked` in newer versions of Play, in case you want to upgrade.

As for the chunk size, you can always use [`Enumeratee.grouped`](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.iteratee.Enumeratee%24) to gather a bunch of values and send them as one chunk.

```
val grouper = Enumeratee.grouped(  
  Traversable.take[Array[Double]](100) &>> Iteratee.consume()  
)
```

Then you'd do something like

```
Ok.stream(enumerator &> grouper >>> Enumerator.eof)
```

Comment: +1 Thanks for answer, is very useful, im very noob in scala it's still complex to me to read and understand code easily. But in the link you provide says *This demo shows how to generate a zip file on-the-fly and directly stream it to an HTTP client **without loading it in memory** or storing it in a file.* And what you say about gigabytes it's contradictory about outOfMemory

Comment: Yeah I know, Scala is hard. Took me a while as well, and I'm still a beginner. But you can use more Java/OO-like code in the beginning and then [start experimenting with functional programming](https://www.coursera.org/course/progfun). Don't take the _"without loading it in memory"_ literally. You have to store _something_ in memory. It just means that you don't generate the whole zip file in memory, and then send it to the client, but instead stream it as you generate it. And as long as the client comes along and picks up the stream, it gets deleted from memory just as fast.

Comment: Ok , for example `Enumerator.forStream()` let you the possibility to set a chunkSize, in this case when it's going to chunk, like the comment in `1024*8` or in every write of the output stream? If it's that the magic code in `grouper` is useful :D

Comment: `Traversable.take`  doesn't compile i need to import something special?

Comment: Yes, import play.api.libs.iteratee.Traversable (you can search in Play's scaladocs for the class if you encounter that in the future). If you look at [`Enumerator.fromStream()`](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2‌​.1.x/framework/src/iteratees/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/iteratee/Enumerator.sca‌​la#L592), you can see that it just reads a certain amount of bytes from the InputStream into an array and feeds it into the Enumerator. The default for that is `1024 * 8`. I'm not sure if the enumerator gets re-chunked into 8k blocks when sending, as @goral seemed to suggest.