# Return JGits git.archive() OutputStream as Enumerator

Tags: git, scala, playframework, zip, jgit

I'm new to Scala and what I'm trying to do is to zip a git repository via JGit and offer the zipped file as download. 
The idea is that there won't be Zip-File generated beforehand but instead it will be zipped on the fly and transmitted right away. I've got it to work without using Jgit and something like this example https://gist.github.com/gre/4058734

However since there is already a git.archive method that writes a zipped repository into an OutputStream, I would like to use it instead of the Solution above.
I've tried the following but it didn't work and I can't seem to find out why.

```
  ArchiveFormats.registerAll();

  var enum = Enumerator.outputStream { os =>   
    git.archive()
      .setTree(git.getRepository.resolve("master"))
      .setFormat("zip")
      .setOutputStream(os)
      .call() 
   }

  ArchiveFormats.unregisterAll();


 Ok.stream(enum >>> Enumerator.eof).withHeaders(
 "Content-Type"->"application/zip", 
 "Content-Disposition"->"attachment; filename=asdf.zip"
)
```

Comment: Can you expand a bit more on what you mean "it didn't seem to work" please? What sort of error messages were you getting, or what was happening?

Comment: Thats the thing, I dont get error messages and no download starts. The browser appears however to be busy since the tab shows a "connecting" label.
If I use a FileOutputStream with git.archive(), generate a File and offer the File as download, everything works fine.
The idea is however not to generate a File.

Comment: I think i might be misunderstanding the way Enumerator.outputStream works

Comment: In the example you linked, don't you just want to replace the git archive with the part where they write to the zip? they aren't writing the zip to a physical file, it's being written to a stream which is what you want isn't it?

Comment: I did that and it worked. But I would like to use git.archive since it allows me to choose which branch the repository should be in (.setTree(git.getRepository.resolve("master"))). 
I could of course make a checkout, zip it and checkout back but I find this to be a bad solution.

Comment: How big is the repo you are trying to stream? there's a similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23742971/how-to-generate-a-big-data-stream-on-the-fly

Comment: Had that idea too but my test repo is only about 1 MB.

It's not working with the combination of git.archive and Enumerator.outputStream only

Comment: From what I am reading, the git `setOutputStream` returns a `ByteArrayOutputStream`, I think you can just return that in `Ok.stream` without using the enumerator at all.

Comment: Or, maybe you do need an enumerator, just a different type - I have put some code in an answer for you to try

Comment: I would also suggest shortening the title of your question to something like 'Return git outputStream as Enumerator' - you might attract more people to read it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in the fact that `setOutputStream` is expecting a `ByteArrayOutputStream`, not just an `outputStream`.

You could put the zip contents into a `ByteArrayOutputStream` then convert that to an `InputStream` so you can return the contents.

```
  ByteArrayOutputStream data= new ByteArrayOutputStream();

  git.archive()
      .setTree(git.getRepository.resolve("master"))
      .setFormat("zip")
      .setOutputStream(data)
      .call() 

  InputStream inStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(data.toByteArray());

  val dataContent: Enumerator[Array[Byte]] = Enumerator.fromStream(inStream)

  Ok.stream(dataContent).withHeaders(
     "Content-Type"->"application/zip", 
     "Content-Disposition"->"attachment; filename=asdf.zip"
  )
```

There are some caveats to watch out for here, the example above shows how to get around the problem in the question but attention needs to be paid to how much in-memory work is being done.

The documentation [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/ScalaStream) covers examples of sending large amounts of data in chunks.

There are some notes [here](http://blog.ostermiller.org/convert-java-outputstream-inputstream) about how you can more efficiently convert a `ByteArrayOutputStream` into a `ByteArrayInputStream` if you are looking for maximum efficiency.

Comment: I feel like we're getting closer but Enumerator.fromStream(data)
demands data to be an InputStream.

Comment: Damn now I feel just plain stupid :)
Works like a charm
Thank you!

Comment: If you could give me a +1 on the answer too that would be much appreciated, especially as I don't have an environment to test it in so it was mostly guesswork! :-)

Comment: I'd love to but it says
Thanks for the feedback! Once you earn a total of 15 reputation, your votes will change the publicly displayed post score."

Comment: I know, I only found your question because I was reviewing people's first question. It was a well worded question, that showed some research - just remember to keep your titles attractive and you will do well around here.

Comment: Much appreciated, you should have a start as I gave you +1 for your question, you should try to find some questions you can answer, it can be fun and you can learn a lot just reading other people's queries :)

Comment: Please note that you are loading the full zip file into memory with this, it will work for small ones, but surely exceed available memory with large git repositories...

Comment: @centic - I did mention that in the comments, the linked answer covers how to handle larger files - do you think I should put something extra in my answer to highlight this?

Comment: Nobody reads comments :) Updating the answer would prevent people from running into this problem.